# Actions on Google- Can we use Custom voice for Google Home?

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I want my google assistance app to read response using custom user voice. I'm using webhook to send responses to user queries. Currently, I'm sending text responses. I have built a custom voice model using (https://lyrebird.ai/). When my webhook is triggered I would like to first convert the text response to audio using my custom model and send the output audio to google home. Is this possible? Or Is there any better ways of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can synthesize your own audio and return it as Ssml in an audio tag: 
https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml